# Error in flutter project build gradle problem

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration
> ":classpath
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.
> Searched in the following locations:
> -nttps:1/dl.google.com/d/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aradle/6.7/gradle-6.7.pom
> nttps://repo_naven_apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aradle/6.7/gradle-6.7.pom
> Required by:
> project

Comment: You have most likely wrong version of gradle in file `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Check the distributionUrl there.

Comment: in project setting select latest version of flutter path and install latest flutter package also

Comment: I tried to but this was happened
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'androic
java.til.concurrent. ExecutionException: org.gradu
s. gradle\ caches\ jars-9\36b1c611c4a00559c3954fd125034